# PyCryptoDome generate OpenSSL PBKDF2 key for AES encryption

Tags: python, openssl, aes, pycrypto, pbkdf2

I want to encrypt a file using PyCryptoDome AES-256-ECB mode, write key and password to file and then decrypt it using OpenSSL
Python password and key encryption looks like this:

```
import random
import string
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad


secret = "123"
random_aes_key_length = 32
aes_key_file_path = "key.key"
encrypted_message_file_path = "message.out"
dir_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
random_aes_password = "".join(
        random.SystemRandom().choice(string.hexdigits) for _ in range(random_aes_key_length))
aes_key = PBKDF2(random_aes_password, b'', dkLen=32)
aes_obj = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
encrypted_message = aes_obj.encrypt(pad(secret.encode(), AES.block_size))

with open(dir_path / aes_key_file_path, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as aes_key_file:
    aes_key_file.write(random_aes_password)

with open(dir_path / encrypted_message_file_path, 'wb') as encrypted_message_file:
    encrypted_message_file.write(encrypted_message)
```

then I want to decode `encrypted_message_file` using OpenSSL:

`openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -pbkdf2 -in message.out -pass file:key.key -nosalt -nopad`

but I don't get my secret, just some random data:
`{���"R,�b�<�-�`

1. How can I encrypt data string using python in compatible way for OpenSSL to decrypt given my random generated encryption password?
2. Particulary, is my method of generating PBKDF2 key in python
   same/compatible with OpenSSL method?

Comment: Please add your imports to your code.

Comment: side note: if you have a choice: do not use ECB... see e.g.: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/24839

Comment: @hiroprotagonist - I am aware of security considerations of AES ECB mode, it is for very specific purposes and does not intend to provide any high measure cryptographic security

Comment: Try the following: In your `openssl`-command, remove `-nopad` and append `-iter 1000 -md sha1` which correponds to the [PBKDF2](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html#pbkdf2) default settings of PyCryptopdome. Note however, that these settings are weak.

Comment: @Topaco - the thing I want to achieve is to create default OpenSSL KDF parameters with PyCryptoDome not the other way around

Comment: Then you've to use the default PBKDF2 settings of OpenSSL in the Python-code. Try `aes_key = PBKDF2(random_aes_password, b'', dkLen=32, count=10000, hmac_hash_module=SHA256)`. Note that due to `-nopad` in your `openssl`-command the padding-bytes aren't removed, which can lead to strange effects in the console. E.g. the padding-bytes in your current example (`123`) consist of `0x0D`-bytes, which corresponds to a _carriage return_, and which may overwrite the output. To avoid this, remove `-nopad` or write the output to a file with `-out < path to output file>`.